# How dangerous would this pyromancer be?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, warfare, super-powers

A pyromancer has the ability to increase or decrease the temperature of both objects & air within 57,600 square feet. No matter what the object is the character can manipulate it as long as it's at or above 1 degree. 2,000degrees is the limit to how hot something can be heated to & 1 degree is lowest the character can decrease something. If you have seen X-men first class the scene where Shaw is able absorbs the grenade explosion is similar to what the character can also do.

Flaws:

- Can only be active for 12 hours each day at peak strength at noon.
- Needs a daily calorie intake of 7000 or risks spontaneous combustion.
- Can not produce any form heat if soaked in a standard pool of water.
- If soaked needs 9 hours for abilities to return.
- Can not exceed speeds greater than 35mph.
- After the sun sets cannot produce temperatures over 55 degrees.
- If taken 10,000 feet sea level begins to readily lose oxygen.
- Must be in a space that is the size of a locker room or larger to produce anything above 100 degrees.
- To manipulate another objects heat it must know its boiling point.

Lastly, if the character dies there is a chance that it explodes a creating an explosion similar to the fission bomb but on a smaller scale say a city buster but only if the character is about 40 or above.

All temperature used is measured in Kelvin. Honestly, this is what pyromancers in my world can do but the science behind it isn't really my expertise. If they existed in our world how dangerous would they be?

Comment: Too broad and POB. I could rule the world with powers like that.

Comment: I do like the pryomancer, though.  I think his staff would be a huge crowbar.

Comment: Are you talking about 1 and 2000 degrees *Celsius*, *Kelvin* or *Fahrenheit*? Otherwise I think this question is fine and I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is too broad or POB.  The answer is simple: your character is godlike — the most powerful guy on the planet.

Bear in mind that people can suspend their disbelief for many reasons, but one of the most common is that they can *relate* to the character.  In other words, the character is flawed, not godlike.

People don't mind superheros, but those heros need to be a bit like people... they make mistakes, they can do amazing things, but when things go wrong, they're equally amazing... and by "wrong" I mean, it happens to the character, not everyone else.  So, a character with abilities like this I'd expect to be mad as a hatter, completely unable to connect with girls, tends to trip on network cables lying on the floor, is deeply in debt (mostly due to the Xbox he just bought), and lost his right to vote due to a felony (you know, that thing at the place with the guy...).  Flawed, super flawed.